# Detect subcommands in Argparse

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

The following parser should let me do some sub commands:

```
 % my_script acmd a_val
```

Is processed sort of like this in `my_script.py` (using the list instead of an actual command line.)

```
 import argparse
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='example')
 subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
 acmd_parser = subparsers.add_parser('acmd')
 acmd_parser.add_argument('a_arg')
 bcmd_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bcmd')
 bcmd_parser.add_argument('b_arg')
 args = parser.parse_args(['acmd','a_val'])
 print(args)
```

The result is this:

```
 Namespace(a_arg='a_val')
```

How do I tell whether I ran `acmd` or `bcmd`? Do I just have to figure it out from the arguments?

Comment: You should take a look at the begins library (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/begins/0.9). It will make arg-parsing life so much better. It supports subprocesses in an elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a `dest` parameter to the `add_subparsers` command, as documented in

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='subparser_name')
>>> subparser1 = subparsers.add_parser('1')
>>> subparser1.add_argument('-x')
>>> subparser2 = subparsers.add_parser('2')
>>> subparser2.add_argument('y')
>>> parser.parse_args(['2', 'frobble'])
Namespace(subparser_name='2', y='frobble')
```

That also documents the use of `set_defaults`.